# Can we use Java code in Groovy TestStep in SoapUI Pro?

Tags: java, groovy, scripting, automation, soapui

I'm in the initial stage of learning Groovy with SoapUI Pro. So I started writing simple script in Groovy Teststep editor as shown below

```
class Hello {
    static void main(String args[]) {
        log.info("Welcome");
    }
}
```

When I execute this script by clicking on the "Run" button from SoapUI Pro, it is throwing the following error message.

**Error:**

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script16.groovy: 5: unexpected token: [ @ line 5, column 30. static void main(String args[]) ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: [ @ line 5, column 30. at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:139) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:107) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:163) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:839) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:544) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:520) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:497) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:306) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:287) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:731) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:743) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:770) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:761) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:148) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:93) at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SourceFile:89) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:149) at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: Script16.groovy:5:30: unexpected token: [ at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.parameterDeclaration(GroovyRecognizer.java:8413) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.parameterDeclarationList(GroovyRecognizer.java:7397) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.variableDefinitions(GroovyRecognizer.java:2311) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.declaration(GroovyRecognizer.java:2140) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.classField(GroovyRecognizer.java:5936) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.classBlock(GroovyRecognizer.java:5236) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.classDefinition(GroovyRecognizer.java:1942) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.typeDefinitionInternal(GroovyRecognizer.java:1822) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.statement(GroovyRecognizer.java:1305) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.parser.GroovyRecognizer.compilationUnit(GroovyRecognizer.java:757) at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:130) ... 21 more 1 error

I'm not sure what wrong did I do and what I have to do for solving this issue.

Thanks
Karunagara Pandi

Answer (score 3):

Groovy is 99% code-compatible with Java. So you can use straight up Java in a Groovy script.

Your problem is that you are declaring a method `main`. In a SoapUI Groovy Script step you do not declare a method. You just start writing code. See [Groovy documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scripts+and+Classes) for additional information.

So your script should be just:

```
log.info("Welcome");
```

No `class`, no `static void main`, just that one liner!

Answer (score 1):

You've bad syntax.

Replace:

```
String args[]
```

with:

```
String[] args
```

or simply:

```
args
```

**UPDATE** (log)

MPE is thrown because You don't have a declaration for log field. Try adding the following import:

`import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j`

and annotate the @Slf4j annotation. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981182/logging-in-groovy-script). Don't know how logging works exactly with SoapUI.

Comment: Hi Opal,  I tried as you suggested. But I'm unable to get the results. So I changed the script like this ----- import java.io.*;
class Hello
{
 void getMessage(String msg)
 {
  log.info(msg);
 }
 static void main(String[] args)
 {
  Hello hello = new Hello();
  hello.getMessage("Welcome");
 }
}  Now, its throwing groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:No such property: log for class: Hello error. :(

Comment: Hi Opal, Thanks for the quick reply but I'm not even getting the results for the script after included the line at the top of the script. If you don't mine, could you please share the simple java code (within the class) script to print a string data using "log.info" ? Thanks

Comment: I can't unfortunately - I don't have even possibility to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Hello {
    def log = this.log;
    void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Welcome");
    }
}
```

Out: 
Wed Oct 26 12:22:35 EEST 2016:INFO:Welcome